# Easy way to find an inverse in $Z_n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, inverse

Well, I'm solving for x in $11x=3$ in $Z_{12}$. And the way for me to do this is finding the inverse of 11 in $Z_{12}$. But to get the inverse, I've tried all possible elements in $Z_{12}$ so that when I multiplied them to 11, the answer is 1. Yup, 11 was also the inverse. So my question is, is there any way, aside from trying all possible ways, to get the inverse in $Z_n$? (I can only imagine the horror of finding the inverse of an element of $Z_n$ for large n)

Comment: Are you familiar with the Euclidean algorithm and Bezout's identity?

Comment: For a generalization of this very special case, notice that $11 = -1$ and $(-1)^2 = 1$.

Comment: It is worth mentioning that when $n$ is prime, all elements in $\Bbb Z_n$ will have inverses (except zero of course), but that will no longer be the case when $n$ is composite.  You would require the number you are searching for an inverse for to be relatively prime to $n$.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft , we haven't encountered Bezout's identity yet, so I tried to search for it. But how can I use it? (let a and b be nonzero integers and let d be their greatest common divisor. Then there exist integers x and y such that

    ax+by=d )

Comment: The *extended euclidean algorithm* yields a Bézout's relation between $11$ and $12$, hence an inverse of $11$.

Comment: Note that $ax + by = 1$ means that $x$ is an inverse to $a$ mod $b$.

Comment: Thank you, I think I can go through it now.